# How to edit search form url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, search

I am looking for a method through which I can change search url of rails search form. By default rails search url is something like

`example.com/test?utf8=✓&search=abc&commit=Search`

Now I have removed &commit=Search using this `:name => nil` in the form and search url looks like

`example.com/test?utf8=✓&search=abc`

Now is it possible to change search url to something else like `&q=abc` ?

Comment: all you need to do is add a new input in your form, with name as :q, and it should work

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in Haml. You can convert it in html.erb if required

```
= form_tag search_path, method: 'get' do
  %label Search
  = text_field_tag :search, params[:search], id: "search"

  %label Q
  = text_field_tag :q, params[:q], id: "q"

  = submit_tag "Search", name: nil
```